# How to build a FTP server with Netty?

Tags: java, ftp, netty

I have built a server application with netty that now needs to act as a ftp server as well. Basically I just need to support authentication/login and file upload via ftp.

Unfortunately there seems to be no pure java implementation of ftp so I could simply write my own decoder/encoder/handler set. Apache MINA provides a complete ftp server, but how could I do it simple and easy with netty?

I already integrated jetty for web service support, but I can't find ftp support for jetty neither.

It would be marvelous to get some hints. I think I checked out all google hits on "java ftp" but they just seem to provide ftp client stuff.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's Netty you're interested in, I found an open source FTP server based on it:
https://github.com/waarp/WaarpFtp

Maybe you could reuse some parts of the project? I guess this source file might be the most interesting to you:
https://github.com/waarp/WaarpFtp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/waarp/ftp/core/control/NetworkHandler.java

Comment: As there seems to be no further input on existing "pure" implementations of ftp I will mark your answer as final one. Cheers!

Comment: Repo seems not existing, have you fork to link ?

Comment: Thanks @JérômeB, I updated the link to https://github.com/waarp/WaarpFtp

Answer (score 3):

I wrote netty handler for receiving files over FTP - [netty-ftp-receiver](https://github.com/alexkasko/netty-ftp-receiver). It's small and straightforward and may be used as a starting point.

Comment: I've ported the code to Netty 4.0 see my [fork](https://github.com/codingtony/netty-ftp-receiver). I will try to add features to this code base as well.